# Routing USB under the serial converter - good idea?

Tags: usb, ftdi

I have a design with a FT230XS USB/Serial converter and a USB B connector.
My current layout looks like this:

[image]

Is it a good idea to route the USB lines under the FT232XS converter? Another solution is to spin the IC around 180 degree and connect the USB lines without routing them under the IC. But then I have to cross the USB lines so I have to switch the layer:

[image]

My question is the following:
Which of this solutions is the better one? Passing the lines under the IC and avoid a layer switch and crossing or cross the lines to avoid a routing under the IC?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll have a problem routing them under the IC over that kind of distance as long as you still flood fill around them with a ground plane. Alternatively, you could route pin 3 of the USB connector down the other side of pin 2 and spin the IC around which should avoid routing under the IC and having to switch planes.